# PHP: вывод первого изображения статьи для превью статьи

Tags: php, sqlite3

Нужно вывести первое изображение статьи для превью — картинка и немножко текста.

Вот, например, тело статьи:

```
<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/2.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/3.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Вот код, который выводит список превьюшек статей:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    echo 'id: ' . $row['id'] . '<br /> Дата и время: ' . $row['datetime']
    . '<br /> Заголовок: ' . $row['title'] 
    . '<br /> Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] 
    . '</a><br /> Контент: ' . mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 300, '...') . '<br />
        <a href="?article=' . $row['id'] . '">Читать</a>
        <br />-------------------------------------------------<br />';
}
```

Помогите, люди добрыя реализовать это дело!

В общем, надо регулярку допилить таким образом, чтобы она выводила еще и первый попавшийся текст до 300 символов. А в регулярных выражениях, я крайне туго разбираюсь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $texthtml = '<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/2.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/3.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';
    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $texthtml, $image);
    echo $image['src'];
?>
```

**Результат:**

```
files/1.jpg
```

**На вашем примере:**

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $row['content'], $image);

    echo '<img src="'.$image['src'].'" alt="" width="200px" />'; // выводите вот этот кусок куда нужно

    echo 'id: ' . $row['id'] . '<br /> Дата и время: ' . $row['datetime'] . '<br /> Заголовок: ' . $row['title'] . '<br /> Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</a><br /> Контент: ' . mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 300, '...') . '<br />
        <a href="?article=' . $row['id'] . '">Читать</a>
        <br />-------------------------------------------------<br />';
}
```

PS: Старайтесь никогда не смешивать HTML, локализацию и логику (PHP,JS). Желательно, чтобы все было отдельно. Шаблоны в одном месте, код в одном а локализация в другом.

Comment: А как $image впихнуть в mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 300, '...')?

Comment: Извините, конечно, но за вас всю работу тут не будут делать. Такое не принято в сообществе. Основное, что вам нужно было, это регулярное выражение для вытаскивания первого изображения. А как и где использовать полученный $image['src'] - решать вам.

Comment: Ну просто, $row['content'] итак уже содержит картинки, регулярка мне ясна, мне не понятно, как вывести. Вот в чём проблема.

Comment: Добавили к ответу. Если регулярка ясна, то скопировать код вроде не составляет труда.

Comment: Да мне это тоже понятно))) Если сделать вот так, например: . $image['src'] . mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 300, '...'), то выводит просто поверх контента, плюс все остальные картинки статьи) Иными словами, она берёт из контента картинку и добавляет её вне самого контента а рядом…

Comment: А надо, по-сути, из этого $row['content'], вырезать начало текста (что я делаю посредством mb_strimwidth() и первую картинку и вывести в виде превью. Но как это сделать, я ума не приложу)

Comment: Если для превью и вам нужен чистый текст (plain text), то очистить от картинок и других HTML тегов вы можете функцией: **strip_tags($row['content'])**. Далее уже делать ваш mb_strimwidth(..) чтобы взять определенное количество символов в тексте

Comment: Нет) Мне нужно, чтобы из картинок и текста бралась одна первая картинка и кусочек текста, т. е. <img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod...</p>

Comment: Так мы это вам и написали. Код для выдергивания картинки дали. Код для очистки текста от других HTML дали. Остается вам просто вчитаться и соеденить 2 полученные переменные...

Comment: Так очищать наоборот не нужно. Нужно именно с тегами, и если текст обрезается, то всё равно закрывать тег.